# Master in Germany after 3 years bachelor degree

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, germany

I've completed my 3 years bachelor degree in B.Sc.Hons in Computing from Nepal affiliated to London Metropolitan University and i am planning to do Ms in Germany. Am i eligible to enroll directly in master program in Germany?